# Passing multiple variables in Controllers

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add an update table on a show blade for a Laravel project.

The idea being if someone is paid owed subs, they can be check off on the roll.

I can pass the roll.id into the Controller, however this is a member view so I need to grab the roll.member_id of the roll.id record and pass this into the redirect to show the updated member page

Here is the html table

```
<table class="table">
      <thead class = 'text-primary'>
         <th class="text-center">Date</th>
         <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach ($member->outstanding as $o)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{$o->roll_id}}</td> 
                <td class="text-center"><a href="{{action('RollController@updateRoll', $o->id)}}" title="Paid" class="btn btn-success"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody> 
   </table>
```

This is the RollController@updateRoll

```
 public function updateRoll($id){
    $o = Roll::find($id);
    if ($o != null)
    {
    $o->status = "C";
    $o->save();
     return redirect(action('MembersController@show'))->with ('success', 'Member Present');
    }
    return redirect(action('MembersController@index'));    
}
```

So I would like to add the Member_id into the

```
return redirect(action('MembersController@show'))->with ('success', 'Member Present');
```

So I am taken back to the member show blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing the ID to the action, same as in your blade view?

For example:

```
return redirect(action('MembersController@show', $o->member_id))
           ->with ('success', 'Member Present');
```

Comment: @Brendan please consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: sorry. I had to wait (i think 10 mins) before accepting, then got a phone call. all done now